# Conflict while installing ggplot to conda python 3 environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-ggplot

I tried to run

```
 conda create --name test python=3
 source activate test
 conda install -c conda-forge ggplot=0.11.5
```

but after the last command I get

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - ggplot 0.11.5* -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pip (target=pip-9.0.1-py36_1.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - pip (target=pip-9.0.1-py36_1.tar.bz2) -> setuptools
  - python 3.6*
  - setuptools (target=setuptools-27.2.0-py36_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.4*|3.5*
  - wheel (target=wheel-0.29.0-py36_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*|3.6*
  - wheel (target=wheel-0.29.0-py36_0.tar.bz2) -> setuptools
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I am able to run

```
 conda install -c bokeh ggplot=0.9.4
```

instead, but that is an older version. I am not sure what would be a practical way of resolving this if I want to use the newer version of ggplot.

I could install the newer version in python 2.7 though.

Answer (score 0):

Running 'conda create --name test python=3' will create a Python 3.6 environment by default.

If you take a look here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ggplot/files you will see that the conda-forge version of ggplot is not compatible with Python 3.6. If you create an environment with Python 3.5 then you will be able to run this command again and successfully install your desired version of ggplot.

```
 conda create --name test1 python=3.5
 source activate test1
 conda install -c conda-forge ggplot=0.11.5
```